# Can I direct the audio in Fallout: New Vegas to another device?

Tags: pc, fallout-new-vegas, windows-7, audio-hardware

I'm playing New Vegas on my PC. I want to redirect the audio to my monitor's speakers while my default audio device is set to my TV. I couldn't find anything in the options, is there somewhere else I can specify which audio device New Vegas uses?

Comment: You'd have to use an external tool. Windows doesn't tell FNV about all the sound devices available, so it can't control its output.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a tool called "Virtual Audio Cable" which is capable of rerouting any audio source on your PC. It is paid, but the trial allows you up to 2 virtual cables:

http://download.cnet.com/Virtual-Audio-Cable/3000-2168_4-10067766.html

Another one claims to be free, but I didn't try it yet so I cannot comment it's quality:

http://www.virtualaudiocable.net/

Comment: Doesn't this require that I'm able to redirect the output of a particular application to the virtual device?

Comment: The cable should be able to detect fallout as audio source and allow to reroute it.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't detect the game as an audio source. Thanks for the link though, VAC looks like it might come in handy sometime.